# how to change the direction of menu to rtl ionic2?

Tags: javascript, cordova, angular, ionic2

ionic version 3.3.0:

```
<ion-menu [content]="Menu"
          [class.rtl]="isRtl"
          [attr.side]="isRtl?'right':'left'">
</ion-menu>
```

I change the direction depending on what language chosen by the user ,
it works fine except when the menu change to rtl direction , the menu open from left to right (like animation), and the swipe still from left to right.
Kindly note that i don't want to duplicate my menu , one for rtl and one for ltr because it also not working for the new version 3.3.0

Comment: <ion-menu [content]="content"  side="right">

Comment: i also did two menu one for rtl and another for ltr (side="left" ) (side="right") but in the latest version 3.3.0 it's damaged it's not working, and i can't return to old version because the new solve another issues (like flip the icons when change the direction)

Comment: oh ok, i am on 3.1.2

Answer (score 1):

```
this.menu._type = null;
```

Once you update menu side, set menu._type to null, so it will recalculate animation for new platform direction.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by workaround with css ,
i did two menus one for rtl side (right) and another for ltr (left)
and i added the following to the app.scss file :

```
[dir="rtl"]{
  ion-menu[side=right] > .menu-inner {
    right: 0;
    direction: ltr;
  }

  ion-menu[side=right] ion-icon[aria-label^="arrow"]::before, ion-icon[flip-rtl]::before {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
    margin-left: 8px;
  }
}
```

and change the dir attribute (rtl ot ltr)from html tag : when you need with:

```
this.platform.setDir('rtl',true);
```